# How do i install xgoogle for Windows?

Tags: python, xgoogle

I have tried installing xgoogle for python through easy_install but it didn't work. I have already downloaded the file but

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
```

gives me an error that xgoogle is not recgnised as a module. What should i do next and where should i move this file too?

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip file of xgoogle and paste it into */dist-packages* or */site-packages* directory (that's where python libraries or modules reside). If you are using Linux, the absolute path is: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Then, try `import xgoogle` or `from xgoogle import GoogleSeach`   ---> Should work.

**Edit:**

I downloaded `xgoogle` myself and it turns out they provide `setup.py` file. Follow these steps to install.

1) Unzip xgoogle.
2) python setup.py build
3) python setup.py install

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange!

What you have to do is get the `xgoogle` folder in the same directory as your Python file, and then make sure that it has these files:

- `search.py`
- `BeatifulSoup.py`
- `browser.py`
- `__init__.py`

Then try `import xgoogle` or `from xgoogle import GoogleSearch, SearchError` or also `import xgoogle.search` or also `from xgoogle import *`.

If none of these work, tell us what's in the xgoogle folder and where that folder is.

Tell us what happens...

Comment: Hey, nope import xgoogle doesn't work and neither does the other codes. Also tried on easy_install. Nada. I have already downloaded a zip file of xgoogle but am not sure what to do with it. Have you installed it before?

Comment: No, never installed it.

Can you tell us what installation procedure you followed?